# Haskell parsing queries (Parsec)

Tags: parsing, haskell, logic, expression, parsec

I'm trying to make a queries parser in Haskell, but don't understand how I'm supposed to allow different optional paths of parser logic. My attempt:

```
query :: Parser Query
query = do
    -- add more queries
    reserved "SELECT"
    select <- sequenceOfExpr
    reserved "FROM"
    table <- identifier
    semi
    return $ Select select table (BoolConst True)
    <|> do
    reserved "SELECT"
    select <- sequenceOfExpr
    reserved "FROM"
    table <- identifier
    reserved "WHERE"
    whereQ <- bExpression
    semi
    return $ Select select table whereQ
    <|> do
    reserved "INSERT"
    insert <- sequenceOfExpr
    reserved "INTO"
    table <- identifier
    semi
    return $ Insert insert table
    <|> do
    reserved "REMOVE"
    reserved "FROM"
    table <- identifier
    reserved "WHERE"
    whereQ <- bExpression
    semi
    return $ Remove table whereQ
    <|> do
    reserved "CREATE"
    table <- identifier
    fields <- sequenceOfExpr
    semi
    return $ Create table fields
    <|> do
    reserved "DROP"
    table <- identifier
    semi
    return $ Drop table
```

Which works when parsing a string that corresponds to the first do stmt structure, e.g.:

```
"SELECT testField FROM testTable;"
```

but not for the others. E.g. when parsing:

```
"SELECT testField FROM testTable WHERE TRUE"
```

Instead of trying the other paths, it returns:

```
unexpected "W"
expecting ";"
```

In other words it seems like it only tries the first logic. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your test query 'where' is lowercase. You only check for uppercase though.

Comment: @ThomasLang My bad, the actual query did have them in uppercase. I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `SELECT FROM` alternative has succeeded and returned its result, the parsing never got to trying the `SELECT FROM WHERE` alternative.

In this specific case, I would just flip their order: try `SELECT FROM WHERE` first, and if that doesn't work, fall back to `SELECT FROM`. You would also need to wrap it in a `try` in order for the parser to roll back to the beginning of the query.

Alternatively, you could make the `WHERE` parsing a conditional part of the `SELECT FROM` parser, something like this:

```
do
    reserved "SELECT"
    select <- sequenceOfExpr
    reserved "FROM"
    table <- identifier
    whereQ <- try (reserved "WHERE" *> bExpression) <|> (pure $ BoolConst True)
    semi
    return $ Select select table whereQ
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the parser interpreting a first match as a success. The try method fixed it for me, according to your example.